# Can an Java Annotation be used at `Scenario`?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Can an custom Java Annotation be used at Cucumber Scenarios for additional logic/behaviour?

```
@billing
Feature: Verify billing

  @important @MyCustom("foobar")
  Scenario: Missing product description
    Given hello
```

`@MyCustom("foobar")` in this pseudo-example is an Java Annotation receiving an string as input. And we can receive the input and based on that process it and do any action with it.

Comment: You may check the documentation for `cucumber expressions` or `cucumber hooks`. They may be a solution for your business need.

Comment: But with cucumber expressions I'm shifting from a configuration based approach that the annotations give to me a code based approach. Where I need to create expressions/steps to do the action that is represented by the annotation.
And hooks are just for the test life cycle.

Comment: Can you give us some example? Is it possible to add step `Given MyCustom foobar` ?

Comment: @lojza with Cucumber Expressions is technically possible but that is not the way I wanted. Because that way would be part of the test flow/description.
I wanted to use it as a Java Annotation or similar approach. But Cucumber Tags "override" in terms of code syntax.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't imagine your use case

Comment: @lojza imagine the following scenario, I've a system property that I pass while running the code. The property is `-Dfoobar=true` and then I created an Java Annotation called `@MyCustom` receives a string that translate to that property than. The algorithm for that annotation will check the value of the property, and decide what to do with it. Imagine that in this case, since is boolean, the annotation decide based on `true` or `false` if should skip or not. Or imagine that the annotation post something on an HTTP based on that property value. Hope I could make it clear :D

On the

Comment: IMHO boolean logic which you describe is equal to usage of tags: `mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="not @foobar"` And for value you can use env. variable `mvn clean test -Dfoobar=baz` and in your step `System.getProperty("foobar")` I see that for combination Java Annotation will be easier